# Remove a commit and related changes from a branch

Tags: git

```
git log
```

will list all the commits on the current branch, suppose I got three commits, and I want to remove the one in the middle, you may suggest the following command:

```
git reset --hard <sha1-commit-id>
```

However, I don't want to revert to that commit id, I want just to remove it from the branch so next time when I do `git log` it will not figure in the list. Thanx in advance.

**EDIT**, sorry for my miss explanation, when I said removing the commit id, I meant removing all related changes as well.

Comment: What should happen to the changes performed in that commit?

Comment: Obviously I want to delete those changes, sorry for the miss understanding, but when I said removing the commit, I meant removing all changes of that commit obviously :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To effectively undo the changes in that commit and remove it from history, you could do something like this:

```
git rebase --onto HEAD^^ HEAD $BRANCH
```

Where `$BRANCH` is the name of the branch you are currently on.

Alternatively, you could check out the older commit and then cherry-pick the newer one:

```
TIP=`git rev-parse HEAD`
git reset --hard HEAD^^
git cherry-pick $TIP
```

Keep in mind that both operations change history, and this will require a `git push --force` operation if you have already published these commits.

Comment: Thanx for your great explanation (+1) it turned out that this is not best option for me so I decided to move the first and last commit to a new branch and so that keep the second `unwanted` commit in the current branch. How could I do that? Thanx.

Comment: @Malloc `git branch foo HEAD^^ && git checkout foo && git cherry-pick $OLDBRANCH`

Answer (score 2):

Is the commit also on a remote branch?  Depending on the answer to this will determine what you should do.

If it isn't, do `git rebase -i <sha before the one you want to remove>` This will allow you to delete the commit.

If it is on a remote, you don't want to remove it.  You will end up causing problems with pushing and pulling.  Rewriting history after you have pushed is a bad thing.  So for that case you want to `git revert <sha that you want to remove>`.  This creates a new commit that undoes the changes.

Comment: Hi, Thanx for your suggestion, so `git revert <sha>`will include all commits except the one specified in `<sha>` ? Am I right ?

Comment: No, `revert` creates a new commit that reverses the changes in the commit `<sha>`  You do not want to rewrite history if your commit is already on a remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

Use command

git rebase -i HEAD~N

Suppose  you dont want 2nd commit, N will  be 2.. once you run this command with value of N=2 git will prompt you to take action.. just remove the line for the commit you dont want , it will get deleted...

And to delete tag use

git tag -d [ tag name ]